# C compilers do absolutely nothing

Tags: windows, gcc, msys2

See title: GCC does absolutely nothing. Clang returns a linker error. After a fresh install (`pacman -S gcc clang`) in a directory only containing `program.c`, whose content is `int main() { return 0; }`:

```
$ gcc program.c
(no output)

$ gcc asdfasdf
(no output even for nonexistent file)

$ gcc
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

$ clang program.c
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

$ clang asdfasdf
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'asdfasdf'
clang: error: no input files

$ gcc -v asdfasdf
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-11.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --with-boot-ldflags='-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high -Wl,--disable-dynamicbase -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' 'LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-pipe -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high' --enable-linker-plugin-flags='LDFLAGS=-static-libstdc++\ -static-libgcc\ -pipe\ -Wl,--dynamicbase,--high-entropy-va,--nxcompat,--default-image-base-high\ -Wl,--stack,12582912'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
COMPILER_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/;C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/liblto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=C:\msys64\tmp\ccYYqACA.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lpthread -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingw32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_eh -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmoldname -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmingwex -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsvcrt -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -m i386pep -Bdynamic C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/crt2.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/crtbegin.o -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0 -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib -LC:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../.. asdfasdf -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 -lpthread -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -lkernel32 C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/../lib/default-manifest.o C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/crtend.o

$ clang -v program.c
clang version 11.0.0 (https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages ca391a3660d17cdee1e94d5afd2e72a4f750cddb)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msys
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-pc-windows-msys -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name program.c -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mframe-pointer=none -fmath-errno -fno-rounding-math -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -target-cpu x86-64 -debugger-tuning=gdb -v -resource-dir /usr/lib/clang/11.0.0 -fdebug-compilation-dir "/c/dev/opengl/\$" -ferror-limit 19 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fgnuc-version=4.2.1 -fcolor-diagnostics -faddrsig -o /tmp/program-cff7ba.o -x c program.c
clang -cc1 version 11.0.0 based upon LLVM 11.0.0 default target x86_64-pc-msys
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/include
 /usr/include/w32api
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-msys-gcc" -v -m64 -o a.exe /tmp/program-cff7ba.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/x86_64-pc-msys-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-msys
Configured with: /c/S/gcc/src/gcc-11.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-msys --prefix=/usr --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-arch=x86-64 --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,lto --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --disable-libssp --disable-win32-registry --disable-symvers --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --disable-isl-version-check --enable-checking=release --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 11.2.0 (GCC)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-m64' '-o' 'a.exe' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64' '-dumpdir' 'a.'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/msys-lto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccDITezv.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lmsys-2.0 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id -m i386pep --wrap _Znwm --wrap _Znam --wrap _ZdlPv --wrap _ZdaPv --wrap _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=msys- --tsaware -o a.exe /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../lib/crt0.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-msys/lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../.. /tmp/program-cff7ba.o -lgcc_s -lgcc -lmsys-2.0 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-msys/11.2.0/crtend.o
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

$ pacman -Qi | awk '/^Name/ { print $3 }' | tr '\n' ' '
(list all installed packages)
asciidoc autoconf autoconf2.13 autogen automake-wrapper automake1.10 automake1.11 automake1.12 automake1.13 automake1.14 automake1.15 automake1.16 automake1.6 automake1.7 automake1.8 automake1.9 base bash bash-completion binutils bison brotli bsdtar btyacc bzip2 ca-certificates clang cmake coreutils curl dash db diffstat diffutils docbook-xml docbook-xsl dos2unix expat file filesystem findutils flex gawk gcc gcc-libs gdb gdbm getent gettext gettext-devel git glib2 gmp gnupg gperf grep groff gzip heimdal heimdal-libs help2man icu inetutils info intltool isl jsoncpp less libarchive libargp libasprintf libassuan libatomic_ops libbz2 libcrypt libcurl libdb libedit libexpat libffi libgc libgcrypt libgdbm libgettextpo libgnutls libgpg-error libgpgme libguile libhogweed libiconv libiconv-devel libidn2 libintl libksba libltdl liblz4 liblzma libmetalink libnettle libnghttp2 libnpth libopenssl libp11-kit libpcre libpcre16 libpcre2_16 libpcre2_32 libpcre2_8 libpcre2posix libpcre32 libpcrecpp libpcreposix libpipeline libpsl libreadline librhash libsqlite libssh2 libtasn1 libtool libunistring libunrar libunrar-devel libutil-linux libuv libxml2 libxslt libxxhash libzstd llvm m4 make man-db mingw-w64-x86_64-adwaita-icon-theme mingw-w64-x86_64-atk mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils mingw-w64-x86_64-brotli mingw-w64-x86_64-bzip2 mingw-w64-x86_64-ca-certificates mingw-w64-x86_64-cairo mingw-w64-x86_64-crt-git mingw-w64-x86_64-expat mingw-w64-x86_64-fontconfig mingw-w64-x86_64-freetype mingw-w64-x86_64-fribidi mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-ada mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-fortran mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libgfortran mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-objc mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb-multiarch mingw-w64-x86_64-gdk-pixbuf2 mingw-w64-x86_64-gettext mingw-w64-x86_64-giflib mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 mingw-w64-x86_64-gmp mingw-w64-x86_64-graphite2 mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk-update-icon-cache mingw-w64-x86_64-gtk3 mingw-w64-x86_64-harfbuzz mingw-w64-x86_64-headers-git mingw-w64-x86_64-hicolor-icon-theme mingw-w64-x86_64-isl mingw-w64-x86_64-jbigkit mingw-w64-x86_64-json-glib mingw-w64-x86_64-lerc mingw-w64-x86_64-libdatrie mingw-w64-x86_64-libdeflate mingw-w64-x86_64-libepoxy mingw-w64-x86_64-libffi mingw-w64-x86_64-libgccjit mingw-w64-x86_64-libiconv mingw-w64-x86_64-libjpeg-turbo mingw-w64-x86_64-libmangle-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libpng mingw-w64-x86_64-librsvg mingw-w64-x86_64-libsystre mingw-w64-x86_64-libtasn1 mingw-w64-x86_64-libthai mingw-w64-x86_64-libtiff mingw-w64-x86_64-libtre-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libwebp mingw-w64-x86_64-libwinpthread-git mingw-w64-x86_64-libxml2 mingw-w64-x86_64-lzo2 mingw-w64-x86_64-make mingw-w64-x86_64-mpc mingw-w64-x86_64-mpdecimal mingw-w64-x86_64-mpfr mingw-w64-x86_64-ncurses mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl mingw-w64-x86_64-p11-kit mingw-w64-x86_64-pango mingw-w64-x86_64-pcre mingw-w64-x86_64-pixman mingw-w64-x86_64-pkgconf mingw-w64-x86_64-python mingw-w64-x86_64-readline mingw-w64-x86_64-shared-mime-info mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3 mingw-w64-x86_64-tcl mingw-w64-x86_64-termcap mingw-w64-x86_64-tk mingw-w64-x86_64-tools-git mingw-w64-x86_64-tzdata mingw-w64-x86_64-windows-default-manifest mingw-w64-x86_64-wineditline mingw-w64-x86_64-winpthreads-git mingw-w64-x86_64-winstorecompat-git mingw-w64-x86_64-xxhash mingw-w64-x86_64-xz mingw-w64-x86_64-zlib mingw-w64-x86_64-zstd mintty mpc mpdecimal mpfr msys2-keyring msys2-launcher msys2-runtime msys2-runtime-devel msys2-w32api-headers msys2-w32api-runtime nano ncurses neofetch nettle openssh openssl p11-kit pacman pacman-contrib pacman-mirrors patch patchutils pcre pcre2 perl perl-Authen-SASL perl-Clone perl-Convert-BinHex perl-Encode-Locale perl-Error perl-File-Listing perl-HTML-Parser perl-HTML-Tagset perl-HTTP-Cookies perl-HTTP-Daemon perl-HTTP-Date perl-HTTP-Message perl-HTTP-Negotiate perl-IO-HTML perl-IO-Socket-SSL perl-IO-Stringy perl-LWP-MediaTypes perl-Locale-Gettext perl-MIME-tools perl-MailTools perl-Module-Build perl-Net-HTTP perl-Net-SMTP-SSL perl-Net-SSLeay perl-TermReadKey perl-Test-Pod perl-TimeDate perl-Try-Tiny perl-URI perl-WWW-RobotRules perl-XML-Parser perl-YAML-Syck perl-inc-latest perl-libwww pinentry pkgconf pkgfile python quilt rebase reflex scons sed swig tar tcl texinfo texinfo-tex tftp-hpa time ttyrec tzcode unrar util-linux vim wget which windows-default-manifest xmlto xxhash xz zlib zstd
```

Comment: Just in case, disable your antivirus and reinstall. Next, your GCC says it targets `x86_64-w64-mingw32`, while Clang targets `x86_64-pc-windows-msys`, this doesn't look right. Did you manually add MSYS2 directories to PATH? What [MSYS2 environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/) are you running (indicated by magenta text in the terminal prompt), and is it the one you want to be using?

Comment: do you suppose having msys2 in path was the problem? i guess i can't check now because reinstalling fixed it

Comment: There are several directories with executables, and depending on the MSYS2 enviroment, different combinatìons of them will be in PATH. The error looks like you've been using `MSYS` environment, with `/mingw64/bin` manually added to PATH, or something. By default MSYS2 ignores Windows PATH and overrides it, but you can tell it to respect it, which you possibly did.